# new es6 array loop method doesn't work with me for(element of Arr)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i tried to change the background color for boxes and when the pointer comes to box with class blue
continue
i use Es6 array loop for ( element of Array) but it doesn't work with me

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
var Arr = Array.from(boxes);

for (let cur of Arr) {
  if (Arr.className.includes('blue')) {
    continue;
  }
  cur.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

```html
<div class="box green">Green</div>
<div class="box red">Red</div>
<div class="box black">Black</div>
```

Comment: It should be `cur.className` instead of `Arr.className`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a mistake in the loop.  `Arr.className.includes('blue')` should be `cur.className.includes('blue')`

Check this snippet

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
var Arr = Array.from(boxes);

for (let cur of Arr) {
  if (cur.className.includes('blue')) {
    continue;
  }
  cur.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
```

```html
<div class="box green">Green</div>
<div class="box red">Red</div>
<div class="box blue">Blue</div>
<div class="box black">Black</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `Arr.className` when you meant to write `cur.className`.

In this code:

```js
for(let cur of Arr)
```

The element is `cur` and `Arr` is the array containing the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    var Arr = Array.from(boxes);
    
    for(let cur of Arr)
    {
        if(cur.className.includes('blue'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        cur.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
```

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then you should just change the Arr.className.includes to cur.className.includes.

Does that help? :)

Answer (score 1):

Arr is an array, not an object, so it's impossible for the property Arr.className to exist

```js
    const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    for(let cur of boxes)
    {
        if(cur.className.includes('blue'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        cur.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box green">Green</div>
    <div class="box red">Red</div>
    <div class="box black">Black</div>
```